# How is the colour quantum number not conserved in this process?

Tags: particle-physics, standard-model, quantum-chromodynamics, gluons, color-charge

I stumbled upon [this](https://cds.cern.ch/record/2217211/files/CERN%20Report,%20Mahesh%20Thakuri.pdf) CERN article, where I found this diagram describing the process $gg \rightarrow HH$:

[image: colour violation]

I'm still new to QCD, and I don't see how a coloured gluon can decay into colourless final products? Is this a valid process within the standard model?

Comment: see this  "drawing Feynman diagrams"  labeled cheetsheet, https://indico.cern.ch/event/570855/contributions/2315633/attachments/1497945/2331732/CheatSheet.pdf  . "o make sure we never need to draw colour charge in our diagrams, we only allow quarks to combine into colour neutral particles," This also may help http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/Particles/expar.html

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have every right to be puzzled.  To the left of the fermion loop you have a color octet, and to the right a color singlet.

What is actually *meant* by strictly nonsense diagrams such as this is that a soft gluon, of which there are zillions and zillions in the colliding hadrons, may join the loop without energetic consequences beyond switching the required colors. That is, think of a soft gluon in a color singlet state with the hard gluon at the tip of the triangle joining the triangle by the apex. Color is conserved, and the energetics of the process, which the authors care about, are/is barely affected.  Experimentalists often use Feynman diagrams as shorthand cartoons of a fundamental process, schematic trail-maps of the energetics rather than strict mathematical expressions and intermediate computational states in a firm calculations.

Comment: I was not aware of this "experimentalist" usage of Feynman diagrams. That's interesting, thank you for the clarification.